# Why can my program not find a file after saving it

Tags: java

I am working on an inventory program and keep running into an issue. I have some text files that are named using a combination of numbers. I call them shelves. I open them up and edit them to store items in them. I am having a problem after I remove some objects from one of these.

How that process goes is I will open the file. Load it into a JTable. Select the item and amount I wish to remove. Then re save the file. That all works great until I go to open another shelf. Any other shelf I try to open after that process tells me that the shelf does not exist even if it the same one I just used. I can still go through the path on my computer and find it just fine and I can close the program and reopen it and it works just fine again until I remove and item from the shelf. I will post any relevant code below. Thanks for the help guys.

```
String[] binCombos = {"01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10"};
    JComboBox<String> aisle, column, row;
    JButton open = new JButton("Open Shelf");

    tableHolder = new JScrollPane(shelfsContents);
    aisle = new JComboBox<String>(binCombos);
    column = new JComboBox<String>(binCombos);
    row = new JComboBox<String>(binCombos);

    open.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            shelfCombo = aisle.getSelectedItem().toString() + column.getSelectedItem().toString() + row.getSelectedItem().toString() + ".txt";
            File shelfName = new File(sPath + "\\" + shelfCombo);

            if(shelfName.exists() == true && Console.console.IsPulling() == false)
            {
                OpenShelf(shelfName);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(shelfName + " does not exist");
            }
        }
    });

private void SaveShelf()
{
    try 
    {
        BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("shelfCombo"));

        for(int i = 0; i < tableModel.getRowCount(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < tableModel.getColumnCount(); j++)
            {
                if(j == 1 || j == 3)
                {
                    if(Integer.parseInt(tableModel.getValueAt(i,3).toString()) > 0)
                    {
                        bfw.write(tableModel.getValueAt(i, j).toString());
                        bfw.write(" : ");
                    }
                }
            }
            bfw.newLine();
        }
        bfw.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect this isn't what you meant: `new FileWriter("shelfCombo")`. That's creating a file called `shelfCombo`... not using the `shelfCombo` variable.

Comment: Your code gives you the "does not exist" error if *either* the file does not exist *or* `Console.console.IsPulling()` is `true`.  What is this `IsPulling()` method, and how do you know it's not `true` in this case?

Comment: Can't believe I over looked that lol. That is what the problem was is that I forgot to set IsPulling to false. Thanks. Now to solve the next error lol

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
private void SaveShelf(){
 PrintWriter pw ;
 try 
 {
   pw = new PrintWriter(new File("shelfCombo"));

    for(int i = 0; i < tableModel.getRowCount(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < tableModel.getColumnCount(); j++)
        {
            if(j == 1 || j == 3)
            {
                if(Integer.parseInt(tableModel.getValueAt(i,3).toString()) > 0)
                {
                    pw.print(tableModel.getValueAt(i, j).toString());
                    pw.print(" : ");
                }
            }
        }
        pw.println();
        pw.flush();
    }
    pw.close();
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
pw.close();
}
}
```